# get json root key based on value

Tags: json

```
{
  "vitals": {
        "title": "Vitals IR",
        "name": "vitalsIr",
        "formid":"5ed5f7ca158a91827891cab2"
    },
    "anthropometry": {
        "title": "Anthropometry IR",
        "name": "anthropometryIr",
        "formid":"5ed621ac158a91228191cafd"
    }}
```

How to get the root key name vitals , anthropometry based on formid value
for example if formid value is "5ed621ac158a91228191cafd"
I need output as anthropometry need to achieve this in angular javascript

Comment: Java,C#,Javascript? Please edit your question to have at least what language/script you want to use. Also some own effort and where exactly in code level is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a json object using JavaScript, you can preform a for on the keys. E.g `for (jsonPropertyName in json) { ... }`. You can then query the formId.

For example:

```
function ProvideRootKey(formId) {
    var results;
    for (jsonPropertyName in json) {
        if (json[jsonPropertyName]['formid'] === formId) {
            results = jsonPropertyName
        }
    }
    return results
}

var json = JSON.parse('{ "vitals":{ "title":"Vitals IR", "name":"vitalsIr","formid":"5ed5f7ca158a91827891cab2"}, "anthropometry":{ "title":"Anthropometry IR", "name":"anthropometryIr", "formid":"5ed621ac158a91228191cafd"}}');

console.log(ProvideRootKey('5ed621ac158a91228191cafd'))
```

Output (in console log):

```
"anthropometry"
```

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/vgo81stm/1/